# "Connection "default" was not found" error nestjs typeorm

Tags: typescript, server, nestjs, backend, typeorm

When I try to get the repository where my sessions are stored(the second line of code)
it throws the error "Connection "default" was not found"
I initialized TypeORM in the App.module.ts file

main.ts

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
const sessionRepository = getRepository(Session);
app.useWebSocketAdapter(new WebsocketAdapter(app));
app.enableCors({ origin: 'http://localhost:5173', credentials: true });
app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    name: 'session_cookie_name',
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
    },
    store: new TypeormStore().connect(sessionRepository),
  }),
);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

await app.listen(3000);
```

App.module.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    AuthModule,
    UsersModule,
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath: '.env.development',
    }),
    PassportModule.register({
      session: true,
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mysql',
      host: process.env.DB_HOST,
      port: parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT),
      username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
      password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
      database: process.env.DB_NAME,
      entities: [User, Session],
      synchronize: true,
      logging: false,
    }),
    GatewayModule,
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Can someone explain where I did wrong?

Comment: Is `getRepository` here the method from TypeORM? If so, I would suggest swapping that out for `const sessionRepository = app.get(getRepositoryToken(Session))`

Comment: Now I'm getting this error
`Nest could not find SessionRepository element (this provider does not exist in the current context)`

Comment: Ah, forgot to add the `{ strict: false }` as a second parameter to the `app.get()`. Add that and try please

Comment: nop still doesn't work after it switching it to

```const sessionRepository = app.get(getRepositoryToken(Session), {
    strict: false,
});```

The same error `Nest could not find SessionRepository element (this provider does not exist in the current context)`

Comment: Do you have `TypeormModule.forFeature([Session])` in your application somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `getRepository()` from TypeORM you can use `app.get()` from the `NestApplication` to get a provider. Pass in `getRepositoryToken(Session)` and `{ strict: true }` to get the same repository as `getRepository(Session)`, but now from the DI container.

Note: to do this, `TypeormModule.forFeature([Session])` must also be in an `imports` array in the application, as this sets up the token for `getRepositoryToken()`